# How to get started developing an app that changes all the colors of the device to black and white (like a filter)

Tags: android, power-saving

How can start develop an android app that changes all the colors of the 
device to black and white (after asking for confirmation and provide a way to return to normal mode)

If you are familiar with the Ultra Power Saving mode of some Samsung devices, I want to know how to implement and standard android app to implement that behavior for other devices that don't have this option included.

[image]

What special permissions needs the app ? which concepts of android development are usefull to implement this ?

I have searched different android development forums without any luck

I am not interested in restricting execution of apps or wifi or data connection, basically I want to apply a "black and white filter to the whole screen" like this app - [Color Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.knatech.colorfilter)

Comment: yes but there might be permission issues

Comment: @androidXP what permissions could be involved ? where could be a good starting point to implement this ?

Comment: @androidXP I have updated my question to reflect recent findings